# Replace values in window.history.replaceState rather than adding to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, browser-history, url-parameters

On button click, I want to add query params. The problem is if I hit the button again, it is re-adding the values to URL. Is there a way for me to replace rather than add to?

My code:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    let my_arr = arr.join('&');
    window.history.replaceState({}, 'Title', `/${window.location.search}&${my_arr}`);
});
```

On first click if it adds my query params: `a=1&b=2`.

If I click the button again with new values, it is re-adding the `a=5&b=2` to the previous value making it look like: `a=1&b=2&a=5&b=2`.

Is there a way for it to replace those values instead of adding to it?

Comment: Do you need to support other query string parameters that are NOT set in your array?

Comment: @Chase, no i don't. I just want to replace everytime I click the button rather than add to

Comment: `${window.location.search}&` should be `?`, then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that also preserved existing values, only overwriting the ones that you specify.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  const testFallbackValue = "?a=33&b=77&c=234"; // Just for demonstration
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search || testFallbackValue);
  const myNewValue = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
  };
  Object.entries(myNewValue).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    searchParams.set(k, v);
  });
  console.log(searchParams.toString());
  // Uncomment when ready to replace state
  //window.history.replaceState({}, 'Title', `/?${searchParams.toString()}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

If you do not want to keep other existing values, you can also ignore passing the current search string to URLSearchParams constructor.